# JavaScript p5.js: ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, p5.js, referenceerror

My code so far is supposed to be able to create a blank canvas with a snake and food, everytime my snake is on the food, the food should find a new location and the food is supposed to be aligned with the snake on a 'grid' but right now it is not. That is my first problem and also in the console I do get this error:

```
ReferenceError: floor is not defined
```

Note that `floor` is supposed to be defined by [p5.js](https://p5js.org).

How to do this and how to fix the error?

Here is my code:

```
var snake;

var scl = 10;
var food;

var columns = floor(width/scl);
var rows = floor(height/scl);

function setup()
{
  //Sets the Canvas
  createCanvas(700, 700);

  //Creates a new object using the variable snake
  snake = new Snake();

  food = new Food();

  //Sets the frame rate
  frameRate(10);

}

function draw()
{
  //Sets the Background, number implies the colour
  background(45);

  //Adds all the values set within the function to the snake
  snake.updateSnake();
  snake.showSnake();
  snake.keyPressed();

  food.showFood();
  food.updateFood();

  if(snake.eatFood(food))
  {
    food.updateFood();
  }
}


function Food()
{
  this.x = random(0,700);
  this.y = random(0,700);

  this.updateFood = function()
  {
    this.pos = createVector(floor(random(columns)), floor(random(rows)));
    this.pos.mult(scl);
  }

  this.showFood = function()
  {
    fill(255, 0, 10);
    rect(food.x, food.y, scl, scl);
  }

}

function Snake()
{
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;

  this.xspeed = 0;
  this.yspeed = 0;

  this.updateSnake = function()
  {
    this.x = this.x + this.xspeed * scl;
    this.y = this.y + this.yspeed * scl;

    this.x = constrain(this.x, 0, width - scl);
    this.y = constrain(this.y, 0, height - scl);
  }

  this.showSnake = function()
  {
    fill(255);
    rect(this.x, this.y, scl, scl);
  }

  this.direction = function(x, y)
  {
    this.xspeed = x;
    this.yspeed = y;
  }

  this.eatFood = function(pos)
  {
    var distance = dist(this.x, this.y, pos.x, pos.y);

    if(distance < 1)
    {
      return true;

      console.log("WITHIN RANGE");

    }else
    {
      return false;

      console.log("OUTSIDE RANGE");

    }
  }

  this.keyPressed = function()
  {
    if (keyCode === UP_ARROW)
    {
      snake.direction(0, -1);
    } else if (keyCode === DOWN_ARROW)
    {
      snake.direction(0, 1);
    } else if (keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW)
    {
      snake.direction(1, 0);
    } else if (keyCode === LEFT_ARROW)
    {
      snake.direction(-1, 0);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `Math.floor` is what you want

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: @Presisor I didn't downvote you, but you're probably getting downvoted for a couple reasons: first, you've posted a ton of code for a single error. You should try to post a [mcve] that shows your problem in as few lines of code as possible, while still being a full example that we can copy and paste to see the error ourselves. Secondly, you've tagged this with [tag:javascript], which means that you're attracting a bunch of JavaScript developers who have never heard of [tag:p5.js]. To them, it looks like a simple typo because they think you're looking for the `Math.floor()` function.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is using the JavaScript `Math.floor()` function. You're trying to use the P5.js `floor()` function.

You can't use P5.js functions until after the `setup()` function has been called. In other words, you want to do something like this:

```
var columns;
var rows;

function setup()
{
  //Sets the Canvas
  createCanvas(700, 700);

  //Creates a new object using the variable snake
  snake = new Snake();

  food = new Food();

  //Sets the frame rate
  frameRate(10);

  columns = floor(width/scl);
  rows = floor(height/scl);

}
```

More info can be found in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/floor).

(Disclaimer: the P5.js `floor()` function is almost definitely using the `Math.floor()` function behind the scenes. But in general you should use P5.js functions whenever you can. That's why they're there.)

Also note that you need to do this in the `setup()` function for similar reasons related to the `width` and `height` variables: they just have default values until after `createCanvas()` is called.

See also: [Why can't I assign variables using p5 functions and variables before `setup()`?](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#why-cant-i-assign-variables-using-p5-functions-and-variables-before-setup)

If you have follow-up questions, please post them in their own questions posts. Please also try to narrow your problem down to a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of posting your entire sketch. Good luck.

Comment: Are you saying that p5.js dumps a shedload of globals into the gloal environment? Blech.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder By default, yep, stuff goes in the global environment. They call this "global mode". You can also run in "instance mode" where stuff goes inside a variable: https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Global-and-instance-mode

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Added a link to the FAQ. (Good catch with the `Math.floor()` thing. I blame copy-paste :p)